# How do I click on a button go to the previous website, and repeat itself with the next button?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

```
url ='https://www.healthgrades.com/family-marriage-counseling-directory'
driver.minimize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")


length =  len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-qa-target='provider-details-provider-name']"))


report1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class = 'button']")
report1.click()


for i in range(length):


    def name():
        for name in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1[data-qa-target='ProviderDisplayName']"):
          print(name.text)
          phone()
    def phone():
        for phone in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='click-to-call-button-secondary hg-track mobile-click-to-call']"):
          print(phone.text)
          back()

    def back():
        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
        btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//a[@class = 'button'])[{i}]").click()
        name()

    name()


driver.quit()
```

Hey guys, I am trying to click the button 'view profile' on the website, then scrape the name and phone number and then go back to the starting website. Now I want to repeat this but not with same Button, but with the next Button in line. I tried doing this with a for loop and putting the variable after the button (4th last line). With numbers everything works fine but not with the variable. Every help much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scroll to each element, and click on view profile and then go back to previous UI screen as well. Here is the code that is doing everything in this regards :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.healthgrades.com/family-marriage-counseling-directory")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
length =  len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-qa-target='provider-details-provider-name']"))
#elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@data-qa-target='provider-details-provider-name']")
j = 0
for i in range(length):
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@data-qa-target='provider-details-provider-name']")
    print(elements[j].text)
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elements[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//ancestor::div[contains(@class,'card-summary')]/following-sibling::div[contains(@class,'card-cta')]/a")).click().perform()

    time.sleep(2)
    print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='toggle-phone-number-button']"))).text)
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
    time.sleep(2)
    j = j + 1
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**PS :** regarding mixing of implicit/explicit waits, I think this is requires in this case since, `find_elements` usage implicit wait, where as to click on few elements we need explicit waits and `time.sleep()` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rearrange your code in several points.
I would remove `name()`, `phone()` and `back()` methods, making them simple flat code inside the for loop.
You will have to add a wait after clicking the back button to let the next `btn` loaded.
You should get these `btn` element each time to avoid stale element exception (as you already doing) and scroll the `btn` element into view before clicking it.
Something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

url ='https://www.healthgrades.com/family-marriage-counseling-directory'
driver.minimize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")


length =  len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-qa-target='provider-details-provider-name']"))


report1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class = 'button']")
report1.click()


for i in range(length):

    for name in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1[data-qa-target='ProviderDisplayName']"):
        print(name.text)
    for phone in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='click-to-call-button-secondary hg-track mobile-click-to-call']"):
        print(phone.text)
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")

    btn = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//a[@class = 'button'])[" + str(i) + "]")))
    actions.move_to_element(btn).perform()
    time.sleep(0.3)
    btn.click()

driver.quit()
```